# Can't hold variable

Tags: perl

I am trying pass a value from a login page to another page.

From the login page, the successful login passes the "username" back to the main page:

```
print redirect("http://example.com/cgi-bin/asg2/Assignment2.plx?x=$login");
```

The main page receives the variable as follows:

```
my $y = param ("x");
```

and prints it using this statement:

```
if ($y){
print "$y";} else {print "Please log in";}
```

When I first get redirected, $y gets printed with no problems. However when I execute a form in the main page:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://examplecom/cgi-bin/asg2/Assignment2.plx">

        <div id="choices">

            <h2>Make a Choice</h2>

            <input class="css-checkbox" id="Kadinski1" name="Painting" type="radio" value="Autumn in Bavaria -Wassily Kandinsky" /><span id="Kad1">Autumn in Bavaria</span><br />
            <input id="Kadinski2" name="Painting" type="radio" value="Movement I - Wassily Kadinsky" /><span id="Kad2">Movement I</span><br />
            <input id="Tamara1" name="Painting" type="radio" value="Autoportrait - Tamara De Lempicka" /><span id="Tam1">Autoportrait</span><br />
            <input id="Tamara2" name="Painting" type="radio" value="Group of Four Nudes - Tamara De Lempicka" /><span id="Tam2">Group of Four Nudes</span><br />
            <input id="Frida1" name="Painting" type="radio" value="Moses - Frida Kahlo" /><span id="Fri1">Moses</span><br />
            <input id="Frida2" name="Painting" type="radio" value="What the Water Gave Me - Frida Kahlo" /><span id="Fri2">What the Water Gave Me</span><br />
            <input id="Vincent1" name="Painting" type="radio" value="Skull of a Skeleton with a Burning Cigarette - Vincent van Gogh" /><span id="Vin1">Skull of a Skeleton with a Burning Cigarette</span><br />
            <input id="Vincent2" name="Painting" type="radio" value="Cafe Terrace on the Place du Forum - Vincent van Gogh" /><span id="Vin2">Cafe Terrace on the Place du Forum</span><br />
            <input id="Salvador1" name="Painting" type="radio" value="Swans Reflecting Elephants - Salvador Dali" /><span id="Sal1">Swans Reflecting Elephants</span><br />
            <input id="Salvador2" name="Painting" type="radio" value="The Persistence of Memory - Salvador Dali" /><span id="Sal2">The Persistence of Memory</span><br />               
            <br />              
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>

</form>
```

it can't hold the value of $y and it prints the "else" statement no matter what I do. Please help!

Comment: You would also have to send the username as a parameter when you submit the form, e.g. by putting it in a hidden form field. But session management is a huge pain in CGI.pm; you should use a framework with session management built-in, like [Dancer2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2), [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious), [Catalyst](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst), or even [CGI::Application](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Application).

Comment: Whats the action value in the form tag?

Comment: The form has no input named `x`, so of course `$y` is never set.

Comment: @ikegami x comes from the redirect ?x=login

Comment: @Godiegogo When you submit the form, it's a new HTTP request, totally independent of the redirect. There's no `<input name="x">` element in the form, and you don't pass an `x` parameter in the `action` attribute of the `<form>`, so no `x` parameter is sent in the request.

Comment: Re "*x comes from the redirect ?x=login*", No, there's `?x=login` in the url (`action="http://examplecom/cgi-bin/asg2/Assignment2.plx"`), and even if there was, you would need `urlparam('x')`.

Comment: Why is `$y` set to the value of a param `x` at all?!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us your form, but I'm guessing your form uses the default action (i.e. the page URL) without any query parameters.

Comment: Even if it did, you need `urlparam` instead of `param`.